# Need Help resolving Init:CrashLoopBackOff status error

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

For one of the pods in a Kubernetes cluster, I'm getting the status `Init:CrashLoopBackOff` whenever I run  `kubectl get pods -n <name-space>`. I ran all the basic commands to try and diagnose the problem but not too sure what to make of it.

I ran the command: `kubectl logs -n <name-space> <pod name>`

```
Error from server (BadRequest): container "hub" in pod "<pod name>" is waiting to start: PodInitializing
```

I ran the command: `kubectl logs -n <name-space> <pod name> --previous`

```
Error from server (BadRequest): previous terminated container "hub" in pod "<pod name>" not found
```

Last command I ran was: `kubectl describe pod`

https://justpaste.it/c7h7c

Answer (score -1):

`Init:CrashLoopBackOff` suggests the pod's init container is crashing. You can find how to debug `init containers` [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-init-containers/).

In short, you can check the logs with:

```
kubectl logs <pod-name> -c <init-container-2>
```

Comment: Everything is wrong about this answer: The link doesn't explain how to debug init containers, it merely describes what they are. And your command will fail because the container is not started! Downvoting.